# How to test a web service with different configurations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, system-testing

I want to automatically test http://localhost/api.ashx.

api.ashx reads configurations from web.config and acts differently.

For example one key is AllowDuplicatedQueryParameter. If web.config has

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="AllowDuplicatedQueryParameter" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

requesting to [http://localhost/api.ashx?**name**=hello&**name**=world](http://localhost/api.ashx?name=hello&name=world) will throw error.

How do I have an automated test that tests different configurations, namely when AllowDuplicatedQueryParameter=true and AllowDuplicatedQueryParameter=false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what kind of automated testing you want to do. Under the circumstances, unit testing or integration testing against a in-process version of your application seems like it would make sense.

Your best option in these cases is to abstract the reading of the configuration into a class that can be mocked. For example, imagine the configuration you change is in your AppSettings you might do something similar to this

```
public interface IConfigurationWrapper
{
    string GetAppSetting(string key);
}

public class ConfigurationWrapper : IConfigurationWrapper
{
     public string GetAppSetting(string key)
     {
         return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
     }
}
```

Your components should take a dependency on an
`IConfigurationWrapper`, and use it whenever you need to access configuration to determine behavior. In your test, you can use a mocking library like Moq or NSubstitute, or roll your own stub implementation of the `IConfigurationWrapper` and use that to controll the behavior of the system under test, like this:

```
public class MyThingDoer
{
    public MyThingDoer(IConfigurationWrapper config)
    {
         _config = config
    }

    public string SaySomething()
    {
        var thingToSay = _config.GetAppSetting("ThingToSay");
        return thingToSay;
    }
}
```

And then in your test

```
[Fact]
public void ThingDoerSaysWhatConfigTellsItToSay()
{
    var configWrapper = new FakeConfigWrapper(thingToSay:"Hello");
    var doer = new MyThingDoer(configWrapper);
    Assert.Equal("Hello", doer.SaySomething());
}
```

Obviously that's a toy example, but it should get at the basic idea. Write an abstraction around the external dependency, then stub the dependency.